# Error while deploying release pipeline in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, build-pipeline

I am trying to deploy an existing .Net Core application using Azure Devops by creating Build and release pipelines. The build pipeline worked fine, but I get the below error when running the release pipeline (under Deploy Azure App Service).

> Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a***.zip
> Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.

What should be done to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is because the build task is not configured. You can try to put the below YAML code at the last to make it work.

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

Comment: Can you tell me if this line needs to be added in YML file manually every time we create a Release pipeline? Is there anyway we can set this up during Build Pipeline?

Comment: I am glad that this answer is useful to you. When you need to run a build task ,this line is  needed. And you can check this link for more information. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops